# Include the grouping column in nested data

Tags: r, purrr

I want to run some modelling on each group of variables `a` and `b`. The problem is that `nest()` doesn't include the grouping variables which are needed by the model.

```
expand.grid(a = LETTERS[1:3], b = LETTERS[1:2], c=1:3, d=1:3) %>% 
   group_by(a, b) %>% 
   nest()
```

The resulting table includes `a` and `b` on the "outside" and `c` and `d` in the nested tibble. How can I add `a` and `b` to the nested tibble?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using cur_data_all() this creates a 3 column data frame in which the last column, nest, is a list each of whose components is the 4 column data frame in one a,b group.

```
ans <- expand.grid(a = LETTERS[1:3], b = LETTERS[1:2], c=1:3, d=1:3) %>% 
   group_by(a, b) %>% 
   summarize(nest = list(cur_data_all()), .groups = "drop")
```

giving:

```
> ans
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  a     b     nest            
  <fct> <fct> <list>          
1 A     A     <tibble [9 x 4]>
2 A     B     <tibble [9 x 4]>
3 B     A     <tibble [9 x 4]>
4 B     B     <tibble [9 x 4]>
5 C     A     <tibble [9 x 4]>
6 C     B     <tibble [9 x 4]>

> names(ans$nest[[1]])
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

If a data frame with just a single ccolumn, nest, is desired equal to the nest column above (except for attributes) then this code would work.

```
expand.grid(a = LETTERS[1:3], b = LETTERS[1:2], c=1:3, d=1:3) %>% 
  group_modify(~ tibble(nest = group_split(., a, b)))
```